# How to improve this script to load half of the youtube embedding code

Tags: wordpress, youtube, embed

I have this script

```
$alt .='<div id="fragment-'.($j+1).'" class="ui-tabs-panel">
'.get_post_meta($niphell[post_id], 'embed', true).'</div>';
```

on a wordpress theme which takes the information from a custom field and it echo it on the featured section. On that custom field I put the embedding code from YouTube and I want to write only the YT video ID on that custom field. The rest of the code to be on the script. "embed" is the custom field.

For example, for normal posts I have this code

```
<object width= "640" height="384"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/<?php $values = get_post_custom_values("youtubeid"); echo $values[0]; ?>?modestbranding=1&autoplay=1&rel=0&fs=1&color1=0xffffff&color2=0xffffff&border=0&loop=1&showinfo=0&iv_load_policy=3"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/<?php $values = get_post_custom_values("youtubeid"); echo $values[0]; ?>?modestbranding=1&autoplay=1&rel=0&fs=1&color1=0xffffff&color2=0xffffff&border=0&loop=1&showinfo=0&iv_load_policy=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="false" width="640" height="384"></embed></object>
```

and when I want to post a new video I only write the video ID and pres publish.

So, if can anybody help me with this piece of code I will make him a statue :) My programing skills are zero so... The whole piece of code is here: http://predi.ro/stick/featured.txt All I need is to get the YT emedding code on that script so when I add a new featured video, all I need to do is to write only the YT video ID, not the whole embedding code.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following function would work. Where ever you want the video to appear, simply call the function and pass the video ID as the argument. Just add the function to the right after the opening

```
function embedYouTube($id)
{
  $url = 'http://www.youtube.com/v/';
  $params = '?modestbranding=1&autoplay=1&rel=0&fs=1&color1=0xffffff&color2=0xffffff&border=0&loop=1&showinfo=0&iv_load_policy=3';
  $code = '<object width="640" height="384">' .
  '<param name="movie" value="' . $url . $id . $params . '"></param>' .
  '<param name="allowFullScreen" value="false"></param>' .
  '<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>' .
  '<embed src="' . $url . $id . $params . '" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="false" width="640" height="384"></embed>' .
  '</object>';
  echo $code;
}
```

For example.

```
<? embedYouTube("7DK68JJW9pk"); ?>
```